# Magnitude of the band gap

Tags: quantum-mechanics, solid-state-physics, electronic-band-theory

In Kittels book on solid state physics (*Introduction to solid state physics, p. 167, 8th ed.*), he defines the band gap energy $E_g$ as

$E_g = \int_0^1 U(x) [|\psi (+)|^2 - |\psi (-)|^2]$

where $U(x)$ is the potential energy of an electron in the crystal at point $x$, and $\psi(+)$ and $\psi (-)$ are components of the standing wave inside the first BZ. He does not explain why this is so? Why is the energy given by this expression?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$|\psi(+)|^2$ has its peaks at the ions, while $|\psi(-)|^2$ has its maxima between the ions. Since those represent the chance of finding the electron at a certain place we expect $|\psi(+)|^2$ to have a *lower* potential energy as $|\psi(-)|^2$, lower energy because the coulomb potential between the electron and the ions is attractive.

What he is calculating is the difference in the expectation values of the potential energies of this two components at the zone boundary. To do this he uses perturbation theory to *[first order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perturbation_theory_%28quantum_mechanics%29#First_order_corrections)*.

The first order correction $E_1$ to the unperturbed energy is

$$E_{1}=\left< n_0 \right| V \left|n_0\right>, $$

where $n_0$ is the ground state and $V$ the small perturbation. This means that he treats $\psi(\pm)$, the free wave functions at the Brillouin-zone boundary, as the ground states and the potential due to the ions as a small perturbation. $E_{\pm}$ is then the respective energy correction to the original $\psi(\pm)$-energies due to this small perturbation.

The energy correction for one term gives

$$E_{\pm}=\int_0^1 \psi^*(\pm)U(x)\psi(\pm)dx,$$

where the integration is from zero to one because the wavefunctions have been normalized to one over one unit length, such that $\int_0^1 | \psi(\pm)|^2dx=1$.

The difference of those two expressions,

$$E_+-E_-\equiv E_g = \int_0^1 U(x) [|\psi (+)|^2 - |\psi (-)|^2],$$

gives us the difference between the two perturbed energy levels.

So $\psi(+)$, which sits near the ions, feels the ions more and thus sees more of the coulomb potential. This means that the $\psi(+)$-energy is corrected *downwards*, while the $\psi(-)$-energy is corrected *upwards*, since, as said earlier, the $\psi(-)$-component sits between the ions and thus feels less coulomb attraction. The difference between those two energy corrections is precisely the *energy gap*. Its magnitude is $U$, the Fourier component of the potential.

Comment: This is the best explanation I have ever had. Thank you so much for your thorough answer!!